# Error in report dashboard report generation in Jmeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to generate dashboard report using jmeter 4.0. First have generated CSV file in Gui mode of jmeter script working fine created ViewGraph10.csv file.Now my requirement is to create dashboard report.
To generate dashboard report I performed below steps.

1.Open command prompt.
2.go to bin folder of Jmeter
3.execute the below command.

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -g C:\Users\Meghtech\Desktop\Monday folder\ViewGraph10.csv -o C:\Users\Meghtech\Desktop\Monday folder\Reports
```

It shows below error

[image: Error on Executing]

Here is the file location[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to space in your path for output folder.

Surround path with spaces by quotes and it will work:

Comment: I placed the script at "C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples " folder and remove the space .script running fine but the warning remains same

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the below command

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -g "C:\Users\Meghtech\Desktop\Monday folder\ViewGraph10.csv" -o "C:\Users\Meghtech\Desktop\Monday folder\Reports"
```

If this doesn't work. Follow the below steps.

1. Go to JMeter Bin directory and copy the path
2. Now, open the start menu and start typing "environment" and then choose "Edit environment variables for current user"
3. Now, look for path variable and click on edit and then paste the path you copied in the end of the string. Make sure you don't delete or replace anything here.
4. Now open new command prompt window and navigate to report folder and run the below command

`jmeter -g ViewGraph10.csv -o Reports`

This will work.